# Join two python arrays via index

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array

i have a problem in Python. I am creating two numpy arrays from dict entries. I want to join those two numpy arrays in a specific way like this:

```
# create array with classes
probVec = filePickle['classID']
a = np.empty([0, 1])

for x in np.nditer(probVec):
    a = np.append(a,x)

timeVec = filePickle['start']
timeVec = np.asarray(timeVec)
b = np.empty([0, 1])

for x in np.nditer(timeVec):
    b = np.append(b,x)

# create input-vectors for clustering
c = np.vstack((b,a)).transpose()
```

Now, if i want to join them in a more specific way, like taking only specific items of array "probVec" to join them with the corresponding entry of array "timeVec" like this:

```
for x in np.nditer(probVec):
    if x == 3.0:
        a = np.append(a,x)

for x in np.nditer(timeVec):
    b = append with x values that have the same indices as the ones appended in the first loop
```

Because both arrays contain values corresponding to each other they have the same length. So my goal is something like this:

```
probVec = [2.0, 1.0, 3.0, 3.0, 4.0, 3.0...]

timeVec = [t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6...]

c = [[3.0 t3]
     [3.0 t4]
     [3.0 t6]
         .
         .
         .
     ]
```

I just don't know what's the best way to realize that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a comparison operator on an array, like `a == 3.0`, you get a boolean array that can be used for indexing, selecting the rows where the condition is true.

```
In [87]: a = np.random.randint(low=1, high=4, size=10)   # example data

In [88]: a
Out[88]: array([3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2])

In [89]: b = np.arange(10)

In [90]: c = np.column_stack((a, b))

In [91]: c[a == 3]
Out[91]: 
array([[3, 0],
       [3, 2],
       [3, 5]])
```